# "Not a primitive array" error when I try to pull a child from JSON

Tags: android, json

I'm trying to pull an array from this JSON:

```
{
\"name\":
    {
    \"mainName\":\"Ham and cheese sandwich\",
    \"alsoKnownAs\":[\"Steamed bao\",\"Pork belly
        bun\"]
    },
```

But I get an error, "Not a primitive array", when I write this code:

```
            JSONObject sandwich = new JSONObject(json);

            JSONObject name = sandwich.getJSONObject("name");
            String mainName = name.getString("mainName");

            JSONArray alsoKnownAsArray = new JSONArray(name.getJSONArray("alsoKnownAs"));
            for (int i = 0; i < alsoKnownAsArray.length(); i++) {
                String alsoKnown = alsoKnownAsArray.getString(i);
                Log.v("TAG", alsoKnown);
            }
```

I know there's something wrong with the with the JSONArray code, but don't know what it is. I searched and didn't find out how to get an array when it is a child.

Answer (score 2):

The answer:

```
JSONArray alsoKnownAsArray = name.getJSONArray("alsoKnownAs");
            for (int i = 0; i < alsoKnownAsArray.length(); i++) {
                String alsoKnown = alsoKnownAsArray.getString(i);
                Log.v("TAG", alsoKnown);
            }
```